# Failed to connect to azure sql database with connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, azure, connection-string

I was following the tutorial of elastic database tools https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-scale-get-started

I did everything as it's written in the tutorial, but I cannot connect to the Azure SQL database. The following error comes out

> Failed to connect to SQL database with connection string:
>
> Data Source="testing.database.windows.net";Initial
>   Catalog=testdb;Integrated Security=False;User
>   ID=exampleAdmin;Password=P@ssw0rd;Connect Timeout=30;Application
>   Name=ESC_SKv1.0
>
> If this connection string is incorrect, please update the Sql Database
>   settings in App.Config.
>
> Exception message: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

I configured firewall to allow connections from my IP address on Azure portal. I also added the port 1433 in my Windows firewall. In the video tutorial of MSDN, they skip the configuration part.

Can anybody suggest how to fix it? The answer of the link shown as a duplicate doesn't solve this issue. The previous question is 7 years old, and here I'm trying to access Windows Azure SQL using elastic database tools which is a new concept. If you don't know exactly what it is about, please don't mark it as a duplicate

Comment: did you copy the connection string from portal? usually it should have tcp:url:1433 .

Comment: yes, i did, i followed the tutorial, but it doesn't work at all